# Remove a specific inline style with Javascript|jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in my html:

```
<p id='foo' style='text-align:center; font-size:14pt; font-family:verdana; color:red'>hello world</p>
```

and that in my external css:

```
#foo{ font-size:11pt; font-family:arial; color:#000; }
```

I want to remove all `font-size` and `font-family` in the `style` atribute, but not the `color` and others set in external css.

**Result expected:**

```
<p id='foo' style='text-align:center; color:red'>hello world</p>
```

***Already tried:***

```
$('#foo').removeAttr('style');   // That removes all inline
$('#foo').css('font-family',''); // That remove the css setted too
```

Comment: @John Please stop editing the JavaScript tag out of questions that are about JavaScript.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

For those that aren't using jQuery, you can delete specific styles from the inline styles using the native [removeProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/removeProperty) method. Example:

```
elem.style.removeProperty('font-family');
```

Of course, IE < 9 doesn't support this so you'll have to use

```
elem.style.removeAttribute('font-family');
```

so a cross browser way to do it would be:

```
if (elem.style.removeProperty) {
    elem.style.removeProperty('font-family');
} else {
    elem.style.removeAttribute('font-family');
}
```

Comment: +1 this definitely solves the problem, rather than the accepted answer. However your old IE fallback should be `elem.style.removeAttribute('fontFamily');` I believe..

Comment: +1 definitely the best answer. `elm.style.removeProperty()` and `elm.style.setProperty()`. Thanks for showing the light.

Comment: Didn't even know about removeProperty... lulz, thank you Ben!

Answer (score 15):

Set the properties to `inherit`:

```
$('#foo').css('font-family','inherit').css('font-size','inherit');
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it will help me forever... i work with a cms tha allow user to set what he want in the text using tinyMCE.

Comment: `inherit` is supposed to inherit the value from the parent, not from a less-precedent style rule

Comment: @GetFree is right. You probably don't want to use `inherit`. Imagine if you set `div.style.display = 'inherit'` on a div that was inside a list item – the div would end up with `display: list-item` which is almost certainly not what you intended.

Answer (score 8):

In 2019, the simplest way to remove a property seems to be:

```
elem.style.border = "";
```

Similarly, to set a border:

```
elem.style.outline = "1px solid blue";
```

Should work across all browsers too!

Answer (score 7):

I think there is no proper solution to this problem (without changing your markup). You could search and replace the style attribute's value:

```
var element = $('#foo');
element.attr('style', element.attr('style').replace(/font-size:[^;]+/g, '').replace(/font-family:[^;]+/g, ''))
```

By far the best solution would be to get rid of the inline styles and manage the styles by using classes.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to stay away from setting this stuff using inline styles.  I would suggest using classes and then using jQuery to switch between them:

CSS:

```
#foo{ font-size:11pt; font-family:arial; color:#000; }
#foo.highlight {text-align:center; font-size:14pt; font-family:verdana; color:red}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="foo" class="highlight">hello world</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#foo').removeClass('highlight');
$('#foo').addClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 0):

**dynamic add and remove inline  style property**

```js
var check=()=>{
console.log('test')
var el=document.getElementById("id");

var condition=el.style['color']!=""?true:false;

if(condition){

el.style.removeProperty('color')

}
else{

el.style.color="red"

}


}
```

```html
<div id="id" style="display:block">dynamic style</div>


<button onclick="check()">apply style</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

From what I can see you really need two different styles for the paragraph. It might be easier to set those up in CSS and then just use jQuery to remove / add as you need:

```
#styleOne { color: red; font: normal 14pt Verdana; text-align: center; }

#styleTwo{ color: #000; font: normal 11pt Arial; text-align: center; }
```

Your initial html will look like:

```
<p id="styleOne">hello world</p>
```

And then to revert to styleTwo in jQuery

```
$('p#styleOne').removeClass('styleOne').addClass('styleTwo');
```