# getElementById() how to restore hover

Tags: javascript

In my code I have a popup menu wich popsup when you click on a menubutton. When clicked I want the clicked menu button to stay in the hover state/color (#222). When clicked again, the popup disapears and I want the button to be restored. But I do not know how. I tried to do it with "toggle-active." 
Here is the code that I have now.
(the problem is just the "toggle-active")

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- metadata -->
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="keywords" content="bvdh webdesign, beverwijk, heemskerk, uitgeest, ijmuiden, velsen, noord holland, noord-holland, nederland, responsive webdesign, website bouwen, goedkoop, kwaliteit, betrouwbaar">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width user-scalable=no">
        <!-- [/] metadata -->

    <!-- . -->

        <!-- links -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="afb/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="afb/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <!-- [/] links -->

    <!-- . -->

        <!-- script -->
        <script src="js/action.js"></script>
        <!-- [/] script -->

    <!-- . -->

        <title>BvdH Webdesign</title>
    </head>

<!-- . -->

    <body>

        <!-- omhuller -->
        <div class="omhuller">

            <!-- .......... -->
            <!-- MENU POPUP -->
            <!-- .......... -->

                <!-- menu-ag -->
                <div id="menu-ag" onclick="submenuUit(); return false;">

                </div>
                <!-- / menu-ag -->




                <!-- menu-vg -->
                <nav id="menu-vg">

                    <!-- submenu -->
                    <ul class="submenu">

                        <li class="submenu-sluitknop">

                            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="deco-tekst"><span class="fa fa-times-circle" onclick="submenuUit(); return false;"></span></a>

                        </li>




                        <li>

                            <a href="diensten/templates/index.html" class="deco-tekst">templates</a>

                        </li>




                        <li>

                            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="deco-tekst">huisstijl op maat</a>

                        </li>




                        <li>

                            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="deco-tekst">advies op maat</a>

                        </li>




                        <li>

                            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="deco-tekst">logo ontwerp</a>

                        </li>




                        <li>

                            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="deco-tekst">budget website</a>

                        </li>




                        <li>

                            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="deco-tekst">familie website</a>

                        </li>




                        <li>

                            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="deco-tekst">snelservice</a>

                        </li>

                    </ul>
                    <!-- / submenu -->

                </nav>
                <!-- [/] menu-vg -->

            <!-- ../........... -->
            <!-- [/] MENU POPUP -->
            <!-- /............. -->




            <!-- hoofd-header -->
            <header id="hoofdheader">

                <!-- logo -->
                <div id="logo">
                    <img src="afb/logo.png">
                </div>
                <!-- / logo -->




                <!-- hoofdnavigatie -->
                <nav id="hoofdnavigatie">

                    <ul>

                        <li>

                            <a href="#" onclick="toggleSubmenu(); return false;" class="deco-tekst" id="toggle-actief">diensten</a>

                        </li>




                        <li>

                            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="deco-tekst">over Bas</a>

                        </li>




                        <li>

                            <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="deco-tekst">contact</a>

                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </nav>
                <!-- / hoofdnavigatie -->

            </header>
            <!-- / hoofd-header -->




            <!-- inhoud -->
            <section class="inhoud opvaltekst">

                <h1  class="deco-tekst">Investeer in de toekomst</h1>

            </section>
            <!-- / inhoud -->

        </div>
        <!-- / omhuller -->

    </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function toggleSubmenu()
{
  if (document.getElementById('menu-vg').style.display != "block")  //eerste keer klikken: Als je div NIET block is, dan maakt deze het blok. Functie is afgelopen.
  { 
document.getElementById('menu-vg').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('menu-vg').style.zIndex = "999";
document.getElementById('menu-ag').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('menu-ag').style.zIndex = "999";
document.getElementById('toggle-actief').style.color = "#222";
  }

  else
  {                                                                                                 //tweede keer klikken: Bovenstaande is niet van toepassing, aangezien de div bij de eerste klik blok is gemaakt. Nu wordt
document.getElementById('menu-vg').style.display = "none";        //het hier weer "display: none" gemaakt.
document.getElementById('menu-vg').style.zIndex = "auto";
document.getElementById('menu-ag').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('menu-ag').style.zIndex = "auto";
document.getElementById('toggle-actief').style.color = "#666666";
  }
}

function submenuUit()                                                                        //wanneer er op de achtergrond wordt geklikt sluit het menu
{
document.getElementById('menu-vg').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('menu-vg').style.zIndex = "auto";
document.getElementById('menu-ag').style.display = "none";
document.getElementById('menu-ag').style.zIndex = "auto";
}
```

If there is an anwser somewhere already, I did not find it. Please tell me where it is, so there are no double questions.

Comment: My eyes bleed when document.getElementById is called for the same element 10 times in a row. **var mf = document.getElementById('menu-front');** then use the variable mf.

Comment: There is insufficient code here to understand what you are doing, can you put some complete HTML?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a specifc inline style with Javascript|jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033004/remove-a-specifc-inline-style-with-javascriptjquery)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That is a great idea and a lot less code.

Comment: I did not get the awnser from it Hacketo, thanks anyway ;)

Comment: @BasMJ well `document.getElementById('toggle-active').style.removeProperty('color')` instead of doing `style.color = "auto"` isn't what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set "auto" as a color in CSS. Change it to a color value and it should change. Here is an example with HTML if all you want to do is change the color without worrying about the state of other HTML elements:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type = 'text/javascript'>
        function toggleSubmenu() {
            if (document.getElementById('toggle-active').style.color != "red") {   
                document.getElementById('toggle-active').style.color = "red";
            }    
            else {                                                                          
                document.getElementById('toggle-active').style.color = 'blue';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id = 'toggle-active' onclick='toggleSubmenu()'>Test Button</button>
</body>
```

Comment: yes, I did have a color code there. But after clicking to close the popup, the hover from before does not work anymore

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new class called `active` that sets the color to `#222` then add/remove the class when the menu is toggled. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPYaWP

Comment: no, the hover is still gone. It changes the style for one click and then it stay in that style untill you refress

Comment: It seems to work for me. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWbJda
Make sure you add `!important` to the `color: #222` in `.active` to make sure it overrides the `color: #666666` in `#toggle-actief`. Also, remove the lines that set `style.color` of `toggle-actief` in `toggleSubmenu()`.

Comment: @BasMJ Also, make sure you add the `d = document.getElementById("toggle-actief");
    d.className = d.className.substring(0, d.className.length - 7);` in the `submenuUit()` function so the class is removed when that is used as well.