# Colspan from table doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have an HTML table, where if you click on the “`<?php echo $row["title"]; ?>`“, for each row, it will display the exercise text corresponding to that title.

This is working fine, it toggles correctly but I don’t know why the  doesn’t work. The title only displays in one of the columns, but I would like to display on the 3 of them. Below I post a picture with what I get.

Can you help me solve this?

[image]

This is my code:

```
<tr>
            <td><?php echo $num_ex; ?></td> 

            <!---Click Toggle Exercise-->
            <td><a  onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?>)" role="button" class="btn" target="_blank" ><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></a>
                </td>

            <td><?php echo $row["difficulty"]; ?></td>

</tr>

<!--- Toggle --->
<tr id="toggle<?php echo $row["exercise_id"] ?>"  style="display:none">

    <td colspan="3"> <!---THIS COLSPAN IS NOT WORKING-->

            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises WHERE exercise_id='".$row["exercise_id"]."'";
            $result_ej = $conn->query($sql); /*Check connection*/
            $row_ej = $result_ej->fetch_assoc();
            ?>

            <p><?php echo $row["exercise_id"] . ". " . $row["text"]?></p>

 </td>
 </tr><!---Finish Toggle --->
```

This is my script:

```
  <script>
        function myFunction(ejer_id) {
            var x = document.getElementById("toggle" + ejer_id);
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Do Chrome and FF act differently? Post the resulting html, not the php.

Comment: You could put the hidden content in a div that is inside your `<td colspan="3">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are changing the display of a `<tr>` you need to set it properly when you need to show it or else it does not obey table structure rules.

The issue is:

```
x.style.display = "block";
```

It should be:

```
x.style.display = "table-row";
```

Or, better yet just unset it if you don't want to keep track of the "correct" value:

```
x.style.display = "";
```

*disclaimer: I do not know if all browsers will properly support this third option.*

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7971565/2191572 for other options.

---

You can also use:

```
x.style.display = "initial";
```

but it may not work in all browsers such as IE 11 and earlier per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @ana You're welcome. You can also choose to use `x.style.display = "";`. I've updated my answer to include this.