# Why isnt jquery setting my display css value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is my script and the function:

```
<script>
        function post()
        {
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
            var sub = document.getElementById("sub").value;

            if(name && email && message && sub)
            {
            $.ajax
            ({
              type: 'post',
              url: 'email.php',
              data:
              {
                 user_name:name,
                 user_email:email,
                 user_message:message,
                 user_sub:sub
              },
              success: function (response)
              {

              }
            });
            }
            return false;
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
                $("#mailalert").css("display", "");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And there is what should it change:

```
<div class="mailalert" id="mailalert" style="display: none">
<strong>Thank you for your letter.</strong>
</div>
```

Why it isnt chaning the display value to " "? It sends the email successfully, so it runs well.

Comment: What would you expect setting it to "" to do?

Comment: Maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4033004/remove-a-specific-inline-style-with-javascriptjquery

Comment: @KevinB, make the element visible, which will do.

Comment: Are you preventing the default form submission, so it just sends the AJAX?

Comment: @Barmar I'm trying to reproduce the OP's code and I'm wondering about the same.

Comment: @patrik-Kisbalázs Your question's code seems incomplete, as it lacks important parts needed to be properly debugged.

Comment: Do you have some css, eg `#mailalert { display:none; }` ?

Comment: @patrik-Kisbalázs you want to display the `#mailalert` during `ajaxStart`? if so set `global: true` in your ajax call. This will activate AJAX global event handlers

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have omitted part of the code which may contain the actual error. I've tested the following code and it works as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="mail_form" action="email.php">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
    <br>
    Email:<br>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    <br>
    Message:<br>
    <textarea rows="3" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<div class="mailalert" id="mailalert" style="display: none">
    <strong>Thank you for your letter.</strong>
</div>

<script>

    $("#mail_form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var message = document.getElementById("message").value;

        if(name && email && message) {
            var form = $(this);
            var url = form.attr('action');

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                success: function (data) {
                    // alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                    // I'd put $("#mailalert").css("display", ""); here, otherwise it doesn't make sense to display a thank you msg.
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
            console.log("I'm here")
            $("#mailalert").css("display", "");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Tip:
I'd move `$("#mailalert").css("display", "");` to the ajax success function instead.

Answer (score 0):

From the [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

> These methods register handlers to be called when certain events, such as initialization or completion, take place for any Ajax request on the page. **The global events are fired on each Ajax request if the `global` property in jQuery.ajaxSetup() is true**, which it is by default. Note: Global events are never fired for cross-domain script or JSONP requests, regardless of the value of global.

so in your ajax setup to enable global events, just add `global: true`. This should solve your problem.

```js
...
$.ajax
({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'email.php',
      global: true,
      data:
      {
         user_name:name,
         user_email:email,
         user_message:message,
         user_sub:sub
      },
      success: function (response)
      {
      }
});
...
```